# Mean value theorem with random variable argument

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, random-variables, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand if the following argument is valid:

Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be some differentiable function and $X$ some random variable taking values in $\mathbb R$. Consider the following expectation:

$$\mathbb E[f(X+t) - f(X)]$$

where $t$ is some constant in $\mathbb R$. Applying the mean value theorem, since $X$ is constant inside the expectation, we have:

$$\mathbb E[f(X+t) - f(X)] = \mathbb E[t\nabla f(x)|_{x=X} + 1/2t^2 \nabla^2 f(x)|_{x=X_0}]$$

where $X_0 \in [X, X+t]$.

If we look at $X \sim uni[-1,1]$ and $f(x) = |x|$ then we have:
$$\mathbb E[f(X+t) - f(X)] = \mathbb E[|X+t| - |X|] = \mathbb E[\nabla|x|_{x=X}t]= (\mathbb P(X>0) - \mathbb P(X<0))t = 0$$

where the gradient can be evaluated since the expression is differentiable almost everywhere and the second equality comes from $X$ being symmetric about $0$. (also note that the hessian is 0 almost everywhere). However, this result is clearly not true for $t \neq 0$.

Comment: The hessian has a delta mass at $0$.

Comment: But $X=0$ with probability 0. I'm not sure how to resolve that confusion.

Comment: You have in your expectation the hessian evaluated at $X'=0$, not $X=0$.  So $X=0$ being null doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I see, $X'$ depends on $t$ so i cannot say that $X'=0$ wp 0

Comment: The notation "$X'$" in the context of the mean value theorem, which concerns derivatives of real-valued functions defined on a closed interval, with $X$ being a random variable defined on an arbitrary probability space, is very confusing, as it suggests that $X$ is somehow being differentiated - which is not the case. I changed it to $X_0$ to avoid this confusion.